# How to use ng-class to achieve positive and negative styling angularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

I am developing an application that i need to use indicate red for negative and blue for positive of a calculation.

```
<td class="amount debit">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.model.form.amount_debit">
</td>
<td class="amount credit">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.model.form.amount_credit">
</td>
<td class="amount balance" ng-class="{
    negative : (book.total_balance + +vm.model.form.amount_debit - +vm.model.form.amount_credit) < 0.00, 
    positive : (book.total_balance + vm.model.form.amount_debit - +vm.model.form.amount_credit) >= 0.00
}">
    @{{vm.model.book.total_balance + +vm.model.form.amount_debit - +vm.model.form.amount_credit| currency:""}}
</td>
```

In amount balance the amount will be calculated once user input in either input field. 
The problem is when :

if i input on amount debit input type, it shows me positive value.
if i input on amount credit input type, it shows me negative value.

Hence it does not accurately represent the output i wanted.

Let say :
balance = 1,000
amount_debit = 300

it will show me
total = 1,300 in positive which is correct

then when it is

balance = 1,000
amount_credit = 300

it will show me 
total = 700 in the NEGATIVE which is incorrect. It should have been still positive.

Is my logic part encountered any error?
Or where can i fix?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an example here http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/12791/

```
<table>

<td class="amount balance">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="balance" ng-model="total_balance" />
</td>
<td class="amount debit">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="debit"  ng-model="amount_debit" />
</td>
<td class="amount credit">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="credit"  ng-model="amount_credit">
</td>
<td class="amount balance" ng-class="{
    negative : (total_balance - amount_debit + amount_credit) < 0.00, 
    positive : (total_balance - amount_debit + amount_credit) >= 0.00
}">
    @{{total_balance - amount_debit + amount_credit | currency:""}}
</td>

</table>
```

I used `input type="number" so I don't have to worry about parsing the string into float/int.

Comment: It should work here. However if i implemented to mine, it still does not work, i am not sure why. I suspect logic error, however it doesn't seem like that

Comment: I noticed you are referring `book.total_balance` in the ng-class and `vm.model.book.total_balance`  in the other place. May be that is why?

Comment: Oh My God, careless mistake. Thank you for mentioning that.