# Using ngClass with positive and negative numbers and change color in Ionic/Capacitor

Tags: android, html, css, angular, ionic-framework

I have a data element from my api to show the price and some percentage data. Based on the number I want to give the negative numbers red and 0 and above green. I saw on the Angular documentation you can use ngstyle and ngClass. I decided to choose ngClass so I can reuse the code for other pages. This is what I have:

```
<ion-row>
  <div>{{Prices}}</div> 
</ion-row>
```

And

```
<ion-row>
      <div>{{PricesPercentage}}</div> 
</ion-row>
```

The data looks like this:

**Price:**

1304.53

**PricesPercentage:**

2.33906,
-0.04118

When it's negative I want to give the css class red.

```
.green-color{
 color:green;
}

.red-color{
    color:red;
}
```

I have searched on google for solution and this is what I have tried:

**Solution 1: using function**

```
 checkNumberColor(numberCheck) {
    if (this.numberCheck >= 0,0) {
      return 'green-color';
    }
    if (this.numberCheck < 0,0) {
      return 'red-color';
    }   
  }
```

And I bind this like:

```
  <div [ngClass]="checkNumberColor(PricesPercentage)">{{PricesPercentage}}</div>
```

I have tested this and didn't work. No errors in the chrome dev tools.

[Angular 2 ngClass function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50226800/angular-2-ngclass-function)

**Solution 2: condition on the ngClass itself**

```
<div [ngClass]="{'red-color' : (PricesPercentage) < 0.00, 'green-color' : (PricesPercentage) >= 0.00}">{{PricesPercentage}}</div>
```

[How to use ng-class to achieve positive and negative styling angularJs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45040861/how-to-use-ng-class-to-achieve-positive-and-negative-styling-angularjs)

And I use this documentation to convert ngClass to a newer version:

https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

I prefer solution 2 to work. When I open my app it doesn't change the color.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation of the `[ngClass]` is wrong.
Here is how you should do it.
`[ngClass]="PricesPercentage > 0 ? 'green-color' : 'red-color'"`

[Here is a link to a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jktesl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) I created now to help you see the `[ngClass]` in action.

Comment: Hello Walid, Thank you so much for you time. I use this variable to get data from another page in the ngOnInit(). This is my variable like `PricesPercentage : number;` and I use it like this: `this.PricesPercentage = this.navParams.data.pricechangeper` when I set it to 0 I still don't get the right colors.

Comment: The condition is set to apply the green color to values that are more than zero. This implies that values equale to zero or less than zero will default to red. I cannot relate to what you get in the other component. But potentially it might be undefined for whatever reason. And thus the ternary expression predicate is not valid so you will not see the colors set as you expect.

Comment: I think that's the problem because I use 5 decimals like this -0.04118. I haved changed it to < 0.00000 but still no succes.

Comment: please share a stackblitz of your issue with example from your debugging. That will be convenient to help you

Comment: I have uploaded the full code. The databinding is working good only the condition doesn't work.

https://jsfiddle.net/gfr4sw2u/